# Is "NA" reserved or am I losing my mind?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Here I have a table, eloquently named `Table4`.

[image]

I have defined a Named Range based on the ID column of `Table4`.

[image]

Here I have a couple identical dropdowns next to fields that use a `VLOOKUP`:

[image]

The dropdown is validated using a `list` based on the Named Range above (PatientIds).  And here is the code for the lookup formulas:

`=VLOOKUP(C9,Table4[[#All],[ID]:[Full Name]],4)`

With the data above, everything looks and works great.  I can change the dropdowns and the value next to it changes.  Here is an example:

[image]

**HOWEVER**, if I try to change `Z1` to `NA`, which makes more sense for the user, all hell breaks loose!

Here are the results with a few duplicated fields:

[image]

And if I do nothing other than change `NA` back to `Z1`:

[image]

Comment: I went back to the original state and realized that anything *after* Z1 shows up as "Deanna Troi" so it wasn't working as intended.  Interestingly, I moved `Z1` down between `P8` and `P9` and now everything up until P9 worked properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(C9,Table4[[#All],[ID]:[Full Name]],4)
```

Vlookup takes four arguments

```
Vlookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_number, range_lookup)
```

The last argument can be omitted and will default to 1 or TRUE. You omitted the fourth argument, so it defaults to TRUE. That means that the lookup will return the next smallest item if an exact match is not found.

For that to work properly, the table_array has to be sorted ascending by the first column. If that is not the case, results will be all over the place and a correct result will be more by chance than by design.

For more information about Vlookup and a discussion about the fourth parameter see [Vlookup – why do I need TRUE or FALSE?](http://www.teylyn.com/vlookup-why-do-i-need-true-or-false/)

Comment: `the table_array has to be sorted ascending by the first column` That's the part I was missing.  How frustrating!  Thanks.